# How could I know how much CPU time is used by all threads?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, cpu-usage

I have a few threads in my program - run on Windows and write in C++.
How can I know in the end of the running how much CPU time is used by all or one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetThreadTimes` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx